# Replace appsettings and connection strings Octopus Deploy

Tags: asp.net, .net, octopus-deploy

I am using Octopus deploy to replace appsettings and connectionstrings

In my web.config i have the following these files are excluuded from checkin

```
<appSettings configSource="MyLocalAppconfig" > </appSettings> 
<connectionStrings configSource="MyLocalDB.config"> </connectionStrings>
```

Then in my web.release.config

i have the following

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AppSetting1" value=""/>
    <add key="AppSetting2" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB1" connectionString=""/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

In Octopus I have variables setup with the same name. I also have the following steps ticket in the deployment

[image]

But when I deploy Octopus says

No matching appSetting, applicationSetting, nor connectionString names were found in: C:\Octopus\Applications\XXX\XX\1.0.1\Web.config

Comment: Have you checked those variables are scoped to the environment you are deploying to?

Comment: The next test would be to add those app settings to the web.config directly and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

You are not using valid XDT. You have to tell it how to transform those. In your case, you want to insert them since they don't exist in the original file.

Comment: any clue on how to do this you mentioned?

Comment: @SteveRodriguez https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the *Web.release.config* is part of your package? The [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/releases) is very convenient for viewing the contents of your package. (you could also add .zip extension to the package file name (or rename .nupkg to .zip) and it will just open when you double click it).

Maybe what you're seeing is collateral damage. No Web.release.config was found, so no transformation took place at all... so there are no appSettings or connectionStrings.